# PHP + Oracle Soft Parsing Dynamically Sorted Queries

Tags: php, sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a php site with OCI connection to Oracle 11g database. I bind variables in all my queries so they don't have to do hard parsing which greatly increases performance.
But lets say i want to be able to sort my output dynamically by clicking a button on the page.
From what i understand i can't bind variables to Order By cause in the oracle query, so i can just build an if statement in PHP and assign $orderby variable depending on what order by button is clicked.
My understanding though that each time when order by clause changes, hard parse will be required and my statements will run slow. what can i do to help this? please help!

this is one of my queries:

```
SELECT * FROM V_SOPI_PURCHASE_ORDER
WHERE CONTRACTOR = :CONTRACTORNAME
```

this can be my if pseudocode:

```
if (clicked search by contractor) {
$orderby = "ORDER BY CONTRACTOR";
}
elseif (clicked search by customer) {
$orderby = "ORDER BY CUSTOMER";
}
```

etc.

Thank you in advance!
Maksim

Comment: you have 2 different queries.. and if you use prepared statement, the parsing is going to happen 2 times only.. and you cannot avoid it.. Problem will be only the runtime values that are used in the query string. When you use bind variables for it, you are all good!

Comment: Not having used Oracle ever, it something like this possible: `ORDER BY CASE :ORDER_COLUMN WHEN 'CONTRACTOR' THEN CONTRACTOR WHEN 'CUSTOMER' THEN CUSTOMER END;`, but it may be that this far from improves the performance...

Comment: Maheswaran, you are sure about that? So basically my performance won't suffer as much?

Comment: Maheswaran, i just did a test, not good, once i change ORDER BY, it's doing hard parsing all over again. So for example i run the query first time, takes about 20 seconds to complete (hard parse). Then i run it second time (takes 0.6 seconds - soft parse). Change Order By, again runs for 20 seconds

Comment: @MaxKay - That difference does not seem plausible as a penalty for hard parsing (particularly assuming that you didn't do your experiment on a live production system that was under a heavy load).  Unless something is really, really wrong, hard parsing isn't going to take 19 seconds.  Are you sure that you're not describing the effect of having data cached the second time you run a query?

Comment: My take is, without order by at all, your query will be faster. As Justin says, parsing has nothing to do with the slowness. Just for too much of data,DB has taken time to sort(happens in the PGA) and based on the current load.. the performance may impact!

Comment: Hi, Justin. I always thought that SGA Buffer cache is what is used for soft parsing and my query, if nothing is changed is there and runs under a second. But once i change the query it takes 20 seconds to parse. Running it again will be under 1 second. If i rerun original query it will be under one second also since it's in the buffer. I hope i am making sense, as i am not very confident my knowledge is correct here.

Comment: Maheswaran, so what are my options then?

Comment: You have the columns indexed? An index over the ordered column might give some performance benefits. The mystery behind second time fast execution is the caching of data. Which we cannot rely. Parsing of the query is to fill the SQL cache, already parsed query will not be cached. in your case, only 2 hard parsing happens. All you have to worry is to fine tune the query and identify the root cause.